# Error org.json.JSONException: End of input at character 0 of

Tags: php, android, json, database

what is the problem in my Login code , when i register it works fine and the user can register successfully but when i try to login i receive that error " end of input at character 0 of"

here is my Login.php code

```
<?php
include "connect.php";
if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']=='POST') {

    $email = $_POST['email'];
    $password = $_POST['password'];

    $sql = "SELECT * FROM User WHERE email='$email' ";

    $response = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);

    $result = array();
    $result['login'] = array();

    if ( mysqli_num_rows($response) === 1 ) {

        $row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($response);

        if ( password_verify($password, $row['password']) ) {

            $index['name'] = $row['name'];
            $index['email'] = $row['email'];

            array_push($result['login'], $index);

            $result['success'] = "1";
            $result['message'] = "success";
            echo json_encode($result);

            mysqli_close($conn);

        } else {

            $result['success'] = "0";
            $result['message'] = "error";
            echo json_encode($result);

            mysqli_close($conn);

        }
    }

}
?>
```

this is my login code in android studio ( Login.java )

```
package com.m99.ml99.everyday;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.ProgressBar;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.android.volley.AuthFailureError;
import com.android.volley.Request;
import com.android.volley.RequestQueue;
import com.android.volley.Response;
import com.android.volley.VolleyError;
import com.android.volley.toolbox.StringRequest;
import com.android.volley.toolbox.Volley;

import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;

public class Login extends AppCompatActivity {

private EditText email, password;
private Button btn_login;
private TextView link_regist;
private ProgressBar loading;
private static String URL_LOGIN= 
"https://hanymina43.000webhostapp.com/Login.php";


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_login);

    loading = findViewById(R.id.loading);
    email = findViewById(R.id.email);
    password = findViewById(R.id.password);
    btn_login = findViewById(R.id.btn_login);
    link_regist = findViewById(R.id.link_regist);

    btn_login.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            String mEmail = email.getText().toString().trim();
            String mPass = password.getText().toString().trim();

            if (!mEmail.isEmpty() || !mPass.isEmpty()) {
                Login(mEmail, mPass);
            } else {
                email.setError("Please insert email");
                password.setError("Please insert password");
            }
        }
    });

    link_regist.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            startActivity(new Intent(Login.this, Register.class));
        }
    });

}

private void Login(final String email, final String password) {

    loading.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    btn_login.setVisibility(View.GONE);

    StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST, 
URL_LOGIN,
            new Response.Listener<String>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(String response) {
                    try {
                        JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(response);
                        String success = jsonObject.getString("success");
                           JSONArray jsonArray =
jsonObject.getJSONArray("login");

                        if (success.equals("1")) {

                            for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++) {

                                JSONObject object = 
jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);

                                String name = 
  object.getString("name").trim();
                                String email = 
  object.getString("email").trim();
                                loading.setVisibility(View.GONE);


                            }

                        }

                    } catch (JSONException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                        loading.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                        btn_login.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                        Toast.makeText(Login.this, "Error " +e.toString(), 
Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                }
            },
            new Response.ErrorListener() {
                @Override
                public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                    loading.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    btn_login.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    Toast.makeText(Login.this, "Error " +error.toString(), 
Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            })
    {
        @Override
        protected Map<String, String> getParams() throws AuthFailureError {
            Map<String, String> params = new HashMap<>();
            params.put("email", email);
            params.put("password", password);
            return params;
        }
    };

    RequestQueue requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this);
    requestQueue.add(stringRequest);

}
}
```

can someone tell me where did i go wrong in my code and i dont think it's the server because am running the register on the same server and it's working fine thank you .

Comment: Why do you tag it as `c#`?

Comment: **Warning:** You are wide open to [SQL Injections](http://php.net/manual/en/security.database.sql-injection.php) and should really use parameterized [Prepared Statements](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) instead of manually building your queries like that. Specially since you're not escaping the user inputs at all!

Comment: Please show us the complete error message. You should also test your login script with something like Postman (or create a simple web form to post to the login script) and check if the API works as expected or if you get any error messages from it.

Comment: One suggestion would be to ensure that all routes through your code returns some result - so if `if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']=='POST') {` fails, return something saying an invalid method was used etc.

Comment: i tried testing the api using Postman and this is the message i got                            
       <br />
    <b>Notice</b>:  Undefined index: email in
    <b>/storage/ssd5/239/4104239/public_html/Login.php</b> on line
    <b>6</b>
    <br />
   <br />
    <b>Notice</b>:  Undefined index: password in
    <b>/storage/ssd5/239/4104239/public_html/Login.php</b> on line
    <b>7</b>
    <br />

Answer (score 0):

Check the JSON format receives from the server before `new JSONObject` call.

If it is a valid JSON then post the output received from the API in your question.